# Swift: Why isn't my -1 button working properly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a +1 button and a -1 button and a label that starts at 0. My +1 button is working great, but for some reason, my -1 button isn't working. Can anyone help?

```
var sales = 0

@IBOutlet weak var numberOfSalesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minusOneSaleOutlet: UIButton!

@IBAction func plusOneSale(sender: AnyObject) {
    sales += 1
    numberOfSalesLabel.text = "\(sales)"
    if sales >= 1 {
        minusOneSaleOutlet.hidden = false
       }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

@IBAction func minusOneSale(sender: AnyObject) {
    sales -= 1
    numberOfSalesLabel.text = "\(sales)"

    if sales == 0 {
        minusOneSaleOutlet.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Anybody got any ideas why my minus button isn't working? I'm thinking it might have to do with me calling it as an outlet and as an action, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

p.s.-I'm not sure if this is normal.

[image]

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @BeauNouvelle When I press the minus button, it doesn't change the label and the sales variable stays the same. Also, the minus button doesn't disappear.

Comment: put a break point in. Is it actually getting into your function? Have you got the outlet connect properly in IB.

Comment: @BeauNouvelle yes, I've put a break point in the minusOneSale function and it spits back something weird. If I go up to 3 from the plus button, and then press the minus button over and over again, it keeps printing out "2" as the new sales variable. And the label never changes from 3. I'm confused.

Comment: The code you have posted should be working. You must have something wrong elsewhere. Is it possible that you have your plus button AND minus button hooked up to the same @IBAction?

Comment: He'd get a fatal error if he'd done that. :/

Comment: Change the `(sender: Anyobject)` to `(sender: UIButton)`. Check?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Nope, didn't work. This one is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: @BeauNouvelle see my new p.s. at the bottom

Comment: You've to completely remove the reference. Don't just edit it in the code. Go to storyboard and remove it from the `connections inspector`. While you're there investigate if all the connections are properly made. Then create a new action, and select sender as `uibutton`.

Comment: So it looks like you have BOTH buttons hooked up to the same action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the connections inspector you'll need to make sure all the connections are correct.

If at any point you delete an @IBAction from your code, then create another connection, the old one will still remain until you remove it properly from the connection inspector.

Each of your buttons should only be connected to a single @IBAction (touchUpInside)

Below is what the connections inspector looks like. The image is from one of my own projects, and shows a connected delegate. So yours will look a bit different.

If all else fails, remove all connections on this view (click the x) and link them up again by Ctrl dragging from your button, into the code viewer right on top of your @IBAction. Sometimes its just easier to start again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Somehow I had a reference to the plus button on there too. I appreciate your help, Beau!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.